# Can I add a ::before element to the top of it's parent responsively without knowing the height

Tags: css

I want do **add a diagonal stripe to the top of my div**.  I'll use an SVG to create it (or I could use CSS).  I could do this with media queries but I wanted to know if there was a way to automatically work this out using CSS.

**I can do this if I know the height**, and I can manually add the height to the media queries (it's not a very long job).  But surely there is a cleverer way?

**I tried looking at calc**, but again it relies on us knowing the width or a percentage or similar.

I **don't** want to use JavaScript.

Here's my code:

```css
.itemTitle--padder {
  position: absolute;    
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
 .itemTitle--padder::before {
  background: url('../../../../images/joomla-london-brand-assets/videos-diagonal-background.svg?5d167918') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;    
  display: block;
  content: "";
  margin-top: -56px;
}

.itemTitle--holder  {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: $dark-blue;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="itemTitle--padder">
  <div class="itemTitle--holder">
    <div class="itemTitle">
      The Title of thing I'm creating
    </div>     
  </div>
</div>
```

At the moment it relies entirely on my negative margin.  Is there another way to achieve this?

The main reason for trying to achieve this is because content within the `.itemTitle` div can be a variable length

Comment: Hello Eoin. Can you please edit the Stack Snippet I just created to recreate where you currently are in the process? Doing so will enable us to help you more easily.

Comment: Since the height of your pseudo-element is 100%, you can use `bottom: 100%;` instead of the negative margin and remove the `top: 0;`

Comment: @ZachSaucier I'm not sure what you want me to do with regards to editing it?

Comment: @Greg that's the answer!  Please answer so I can give you your points.  Top man!

Comment: Ah, no wait it's not.  That gives it 100% height of the parent.  But what I want is my ::before to have 100% height of the background image.  Perhaps this would be better done with a seperate div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Gregs suggestion I realised that using ::before wasn't really a great way to acheive this as it would always inherit something from it's parent.

I ended up doing this by using two divs.

**HTML**

```
<div class="itemTitle--padder">
  <div class="itemTitle--image">
    <img src="../../../../images/joomla-london-brand-assets/videos-diagonal-background.svg" alt="" width="100%" height="auto">
  </div>
  <div class="itemTitle--holder">
    <div class="itemTitle">
      The Title
    </div>                  
  </div>                                
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
  .itemTitle--padder {
    position: absolute;    
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .itemTitle--holder  {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: $dark-blue;
    padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  }

  .itemTitle--image {
    width: 100%;
    img {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: calc(100% - 1px);
    }
  }
```